# Rails - Help with a User?Request model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :requests, :foreign_key => :recipient_id
.
.

class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
```

The schema for Request is User, FK, recipient_id (that equals the user_id)

Inserting is working great, for activerecord is not

This is always nil

```
<%= request.user.inspect %>
```

Where this is not:

```
<%= request.inspect %>

#<Request id: 37, recipient_id: 7, created_at: "2010-11-12 23:28:04", updated_at: "2010-11-12 23:28:04">
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think the request model knows the correct foreign_key, it may be looking for user_id in it's table, try the following.

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :recipient_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be:

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User'
```